# Passing search param through php script

Tags: php

I want to create a php script which will send the search param to the [Gas Buddy](http://gasbuddy.com/)

and return the resultant web page. How can i start this process?

Comment: Using cURL library functions.

Comment: It to need a bit of work. You can use FireBug and the NET panel, observe the `http://www.newyorkgasprices.com/GasPriceSearch.aspx` call and do reverse engineering... this webapp could be written in with Microsoft.NET Visual Studio, some var names are not user friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the curl extension.

Comment: Or use stream_context_create: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#72017